# Use custom image as a maptile using osmdroid mapview

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Does any body know if its possible to use an image as a custom maptile in a mapview using osmdroid? For example, I'd like the user to be able to select an image stored on the phone from my application and then have that image then replace a tile within my mapview.
Has anyone got any pointers or ideas of how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the real need. For just one specific zoom level?

However, 2 directions:

- OSMBonusPack [GroundOverlay](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5) let you position a bitmap image somewhere on the map. You can adjust its size, rotation, and transparency. It's not replacing tiles, it's drawn above. And it works at all zoom levels.
- You could try to replace a map tile file with your image file, in the osmdroid file system cache. These 2 utility functions will help you to get the exact file path for a given (lat,lon,zoom):

  ```
  public Point getMapTileFromCoordinates(final double aLat, final double aLon, final int zoom){
          final int y = (int) Math.floor((1 - Math.log(Math.tan(aLat * Math.PI / 180) + 1 / Math.cos(aLat * Math.PI / 180)) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1 << zoom));
          final int x = (int) Math.floor((aLon + 180) / 360 * (1 << zoom));
          return new Point(x, y);
  }

  public File getFileName(ITileSource tileSource, MapTile tile){
          final File file = new File(OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.TILE_PATH_BASE,
                          tileSource.getTileRelativeFilenameString(tile) + OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.TILE_PATH_EXTENSION);
          return file;
  }
  ```

Comment: The idea behind it is so a user could upload an image of a buildings floorplan into the mapview and be able to place markers etc within different parts of the building. Ok both ideas sound pretty good, I did think about using GroundOverlay but I was worried that when I place new markers on the map they might be placed beneith the groundoverlay

Comment: You can control the drawing order of your overlays. For instance, add the GroundOverlay at the "bottom" of all overlays, so that all other overlays are drawn above: map.getOverlays().add(0, myGroundOverlay);